# DXA Refresh token after discovery restarted

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

We have implemented an application that access the model service. When the discovery service is restarted the OAuth token is invalid, so we can't access anymore to the service unless we restart our application.

Is there in DXA 2.0 JAVA version a refresh token functionality?

Comment: Do you mean that you created an application that accesses the DXA Model Service directly (instead of  through the DXA Framework)?

Comment: Don't answer, It's a trap :D (the Model Service is not intended for public use)

Comment: Indeed. But it’s genuinely unclear to me what OP is trying to achieve.